# App store debit card purchasing

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore

I purchased an app on app store using my VISA debit card, the app cost is 1.88 dollars. my fund in my debit card is only 1 dollar, the purchase was completed/succesfull, how could that be possible? and what would happen next? will apple collect the amount when I added fund to my debit card?

**EDIT**:

in my purchase history, there is a message says *We were unable to authorize your payment card for this purchase. Please update billing info.* there is also a message like:

> Amount you owe is 1.88 USD

Thanks!

Comment: Was there any iTunes credit on your account?

Comment: how can I know that?

Comment: If you have redeemed an iTunes gift card at any point, then there could possibly be some leftover credit on your account. It would probably draw on this.

Comment: can you give me instruction where can i find the credit account?

Comment: in my purchase history, there is a message says `We were unable to authorize your payment card for this purchase. Please update billing info.`  it also says The amount I owe is 1.88 USD

Comment: Oh. Oops. That is another kettle of fish entirely. I will adjust my answer to include this.

Comment: You should NEVER use a ***debit*** card to make purchases online! I also wouldn't ever use one for iTunes. Reason being many banks will not protect your bank account for online purchases made with a debit card. In other words, if your debit card information was acquired by a malicious person or organization they could easily wipe out your account and the bank might not cover *any* of your lost money. *Always* use a regular credit card for online purchases. Use that *one* card for online purchases and nothing else. Just pay off the balance immediately each month for any purchases you make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have overdrawn/gone into your overdraft. If your card does not have an overdraft facility, be careful, the amount of money you overdrew can get charged horrifically (at least it does here in the UK).

Not sure what Apple policies are or the time they allow to fully pay if off if they haven't collected the full money though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the help. In my case, my debit card is not deducted. the 1 dollar is still there

Comment: It usually takes a couple of days for money to move: your 'available balance' should say something different to your 'account balance.' Apple tend to be VERY slow in moving money around (well I have found). I bought an app, then two weeks later the money was moved and my receipt arrived.

Comment: in my iTunes, there is a message `Amount you owe is 1.88 USD`  thats why I dont think apple will move the money from my account, because there is nothing to move.

Comment: Apple's policy is basically that if you cannot pay, you are unable to download or purchase anything with your iTunes account until you have paid. I'm not recommending it, but it *does* potentially mean that you could get away without paying for music/movie/application if it's the only thing you're ever going to buy on iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

(There are answers from my comments in this post)

What you have suggested is that Apple has undercharged you for an app. This is highly unlikely, so the money would have had to come from somewhere.

- The most likely place for this to come from would be from your iTunes
  credit, which is received by redeeming iTunes gift cards, to your
  account.
- You can find this number in the top right of the 'iTunes store' tab, by your username.

(EDIT)

---

In my purchase history, there is a message says We were unable to authorize your payment card for this purchase. Please update billing info. it also says The amount I owe is 1.88 USD – sunajledif 12 mins ago

---

There is your answer. Your card has not been authorised, and you owe apple 1.88

To fix this, you will need an working credit/debit card. Then, go to the billing information page, and change the charged card to the new one.

You will then receive a bill of 1.88

Comment: I hope this helps, if not, I have no ideas.

Comment: what If I dont add a working debit/credit card? will that debt will stay as debt forever? and whats the risk?

Comment: I have no idea =)

Comment: They will repossess your App!  The next person at your door could be the repo man...

Comment: @janusfidel It'll cost Apple more to even consider any action, so you're not at risk. However the catch with this is that you'll need to pay if you ever want to download *anything* (including free stuff) from iTunes again.